# datomic and write scalability

Tags: scalability, datomic

http://www.datomic.com/faq.html tells that datomic is not designed for write scalability. So if there is a use case where write scalability is needed then datomic is not the right choice. Is this understanding right?

Further I understand that increasing number of transactors could help in getting higher write scalability. But that way if I want to achieve same write scalability as Cassandra then I have to use double the machines. Half for storage and half for transactors, thereby increasing the cost of cluster. As far as I understand this is not recommended by datomic (datomic advises to use more transactors for HA). What is groups/experts opinion and recommendation on this?

Answer (score 4):

You are correct: Datomic is not optimized for write scalability. This doesn't mean that Datomic can't handle some fairly write-heavy operations—what it means is that write capacity can't be scaled infinitely.

It is incorrect to think that you can add additional transactors to get higher write scalability. The fundamental trade-off of Datomic's architecture is that it features a *single* transactor to serialize and broadcast changes, capping write capacity but providing exceptional read scalability. This is a good fit for the majority of projects, which do more reading than writing.

The only reason to run additional transactors is to provide high availability—all transactors except one will sit in a standby mode, ready to take over if the active transactor fails.

TLDR: You will not achieve the same write scalability as Cassandra, as Datomic and Cassandra are not architected to solve the same problems.